# NSData/CFData bridging with @autorelease but not ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a library that does not use ARC.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
//
//  test.m
//  test-cast
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static
CFDataRef CFDataCreateFromResource(NSString *name)
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@".bin"];

    NSData *binData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    return (CFDataRef) binData;
}

void test(void)
{
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateFromResource(@"Data");

    if(data) CFRelease(data);
}
```

This is a simplified version. The code in test is existing and much more complex. It uses various CFTypes and CFRelease them manually. It was originally C code.

I'm adding the CFDataCreateFromResource code and a few line calling it in test(), changing the file from C to objective-C in the process.

This (static) library is called from a App, that wrap the call to test() in a @autoreleasepool block:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        test();
    }
    NSLog(@"All done!");
    return 0;
}
```

The issue here is that the program crashes at the end of the @autorelease block. It looks like the the autorelease pool is trying to release the CFData/NSData object, which was already manually CFReleased.

I could use remove the CFRelease, but I don't really want to change the existing code. What I really want it transfer the ownership of the returned CFDataRef to the caller.

After reading stuff about ARC, I thought that using __bridge_retained in the cast would help. But because this is not built with ARC, the compiler gives me a warning/error:

```
error: '__bridge_retained' casts have no effect when not using ARC [-Werror,-Warc-bridge-casts-disallowed-in-nonarc]
```

Creating a copy of the NSData using CFDataCreateCopy does work, but seems wasteful.

What's the proper way to handle this here ? Is there another way to cast this ?

Comment: `CFRelease((CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]);` is a bug, end of story. You don't release things you don't own. Although you _should_ own it, since the function is called `..Create..`. There's no way around that without changing some of this code.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is how do I take ownership of that object? I thought __bridge_retained would do this, but apparently not when not using ARC.

Comment: @Droopycom You have it backwards. You were trying to use `__bridge_retained` inside the non-ARC code but you can only use it in ARC code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method named `CFDataCreateFromResource`. This name implies that the object being returned is passing ownership to the caller. But, your implementation of this method is returning an autoreleased object that you don't own. That's a violation of the contract.

One solution is to change:

```
NSData *binData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

to:

```
NSData *binData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

This changes the ownership of `binData` so it matches the contract of the method.

With this simple change your call to `CFRelease` in `test` will work as it should.

Comment: Ah, I would have thought that an NSData created with [NSData alloc] would have the same ownership semantics as any other way to create the NSData.

Comment: This isn't specific to `NSData`. Any object created with `alloc/init...` returns an object you own. By convention, any object created using a convenience method (such as `dataWith...`) returns an autoreleased object you don't own.